# jinja2: grouping data inside a select tag

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Let's say I have the following list that I pass to a jinja2 template via Flask:

```
names = ['Joe', 'Lilly', 'Damion', 'Stephanie', 'Justin']
```

I'm iterating through this list and grouping the data into different `optgroups` within a `select` tag.

jinja2:

```
<label for="names">Names:</label>
<select id="names">
  {% for n in names %}
    {% if n == 'Joe' or n == 'Damion' or n == 'Justin' %}
      <optgroup label='Males'>
        <option value='{{ n }}'>{{ n }}</option>
      </optgroup>
    {% endif %}
    {% if n == 'Lilly' or n == 'Stephanie' %}
      <optgroup label='Females'>
        <option value='{{ n }}'>{{ n }}</option>
      </optgroup>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

However this creates a new label for every name inside the dropdown. I want to group the names and print only one label within the dropdown. How can I do this?

EDIT: I've tried the following code below to no avail.

```
<select id="names">
  {% for n in names %}
    <optgroup label='Males'>
      {% if n == 'Joe' or n == 'Damion' or n == 'Justin' %}
        <option value='{{ n }}'>{{ n }}</option>
      {% endif %}
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label='Females'>
      {% if n == 'Lilly' or n == 'Stephanie' %}
        <option value='{{ n }}'>{{ n }}</option>
      {% endif %}
    </optgroup>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the assessment that this is really a bad design. But to fix the problem you are having you must loop twice over the names:

```
<select id="names">
  <optgroup label='Males'>
    {% for n in names %}
      {% if n == 'Joe' or n == 'Damion' or n == 'Justin' %}
        <option value='{{ n }}'>{{ n }}</option>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label='Females'>
    {% for n in names %}
      {% if n == 'Lilly' or n == 'Stephanie' %}
        <option value='{{ n }}'>{{ n }}</option>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: So you would recommend separating the lists server-side? If so, why?

Comment: It really depends on your complete use case, but if you had `names = {"males": [...], "females": [...]}` you could eliminate the extra jinja conditional. Or each name could instead be an object with a gender flag like `names = [{"gender": "male", "name": "Joe"}, {...}]` which would require a conditional like above (e.g. `if n.gender == 'male'`), but at least it is then extensible.

Comment: Thanks! I would agree handling this server-side is better in most cases as python is much more efficient at filtering data into separate lists. However, this may be best for my current use case as my front-end if relatively bare at the moment